# Laravel 4 - Extending the layout using blade templating

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, laravel-blade

I have just setup my Laravel 4.2 application and am following some online tutorials about authentication.

The tutorials are telling me to add

```
protected $layout = "layouts.main";
```

and then when calling a view, call it like so

```
$this->layout->content = View::make('users.register');
```

But, if im following the Laravel website in creating my templates, it tells me to add

```
@extends('layouts.main')
```

At the beginning of my users/register view

Do i need to bother about the 2 bits of code i added at the beginning if im using that @extends call?

Im really confused.

Cheers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, docs don't say you should do that.
You either do define controller layout (a), or return the view which extends layout (b)

**A: Controller layout**

```
/**
 * The layout that should be used for responses.
 */
protected $layout = 'layouts.master';

/**
 * Show the user profile.
 */
public function showProfile()
{
    $this->layout->content = View::make('user.profile');
}
```

**B: View extending layout view**

```
// app/views/layout/master.blade.php
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <header>
            @yield('header')
        </header>
        <section>
            @yield('content')
        </section>
        <footer>
            @yield('footer')
        </footer>
    </body>
</html>

// app/views/profile.blade.php
@extends('layout/master')

@section('header')
    Header content here
@stop

@section('content')
    Master content here
    @if (Auth::user()->isAdmin)
        @include('admin-panel')
    @endif
@stop

@section('footer')
    Footer content here
@stop

// Controller
/**
 * Show the user profile.
 */
public function showProfile()
{
    return View::make('profile');
}
```

Comment: Oh ok ... So either way is right depending on the person writing the code? or is there a better of the 2 methods above?

Comment: I prefer 2nd approach. It is more flexible (for example, take a look at edited answer)

Comment: Perfect ... Thats the way im currently doing it ... Thanks for your help!